# Country Filter Facebook Campaign Insights

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, filter

I am able to get campaign insights using the code below. Is it possible for me to insert add a ad-sets column & also add a country filter for getting country-wise breakdown.And also a filter to get data for various date ranges such as 30 days, 60 days etc through a dropdown menu?

```
$fields = array (
    'reach',    
    'impressions',
    'website_clicks',
    'cpm',
    'video_10_sec_watched_actions',
    'video_avg_sec_watched_actions',
);  


$params = array (
    'date_preset'=>'last_30_days',
    'data_columns'=>"['adgroup_id','actions','reach']",
);

?>


<?php

$campaign = new Campaign($campaign->id);
$insights = $campaign->getinsights($fields, $params);

foreach ($insights as $insight) {
        echo '<td>'.$insight->reach. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$insight->impressions. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$insight->website_clicks. '</td>';
         echo '<td>' .round($insight->cpm, 1). '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$insight->video_avg_sec_watched_actions. '</td>';
```

Comment: Can you include your Campaign class, without any reference we can't give options on solutions

Comment: I don't know what is a campaign class but for campaign insights I am using 
$account = new AdAccount('act_XXXXXX');
$fields = array(
  CampaignFields::NAME,
  CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
  CampaignFields::STATUS,
     CampaignFields::START_TIME,
     CampaignFields::STOP_TIME,
);